# How to strip out an attribute from Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object being returned from my js code (see image below)

[image: Object being returned at runtime]

I would like to know what would be the most convenient way of stripping out an attribute from this object. Example what if I want to remove the `Id` attribute from the above mentioned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `Id` attribute, you have just to:

```
delete object.Id;
```